# Difference between Ethernet splitter and switch 

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, switch, splitter

I have one Ethernet port that is wired directly to the router on another level.  However, I want to run a desktop and a server both off this one Ethernet port.  Can anyone tell me the difference between an Ethernet splitter and a switch?

Also, will either the splitter or switch slow down the connection as opposed to just one connection?

Comment: If it were 2 computers that never accessed the network at the same time, maybe ok.  But even *if* the workstation could access the server, it would see some serious lag.  I can't even think of a viable route it might take.  Better go with a switch.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

An Ethernet splitter takes advantage of the fact that 10MBit and 100Mbit Ethernet [only use 4 wires](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hack-your-House-Run-both-ethernet-and-phone-over-/step1/Theory/), even though the cable (almost certainly) contains 8 wires. The splitter consists of two pieces (see picture): one is connected to each end of the existing cable, providing the appearance of two ports at each end. Each link has 4 dedicated wires, so there is no risk of packet collisions. Gigabit Ethernet does require all 8 wires, so 100MBit (full duplex) is the limit through a splitter; a Gigabit switch would be required to increase the bandwidth. Also, if your router only has one Ethernet port, then using a splitter is not an option.

[image: Ethernet splitter]

Referring to your [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/105406/linksys-by-cisco-ezxs55w-etherfast-10-100-5-port-workgroup-switch), I've listed the main pros and cons of each option:

### Ethernet splitter

- + *Ought* to be cheapest
- + Passive; doesn't require a power supply
- - Limited to providing one extra port, at 100MBit/s
- - Destination switch/router must have two free Ethernet ports

### 100MBit/s switch

- + Potential for many extra Ethernet ports
- - Requires some set-up
- - Requires a power supply (unless powered by [PoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet))

### Gigabit switch

- + Higher bandwidth
- - Most expensive
- - Requires the rest of the network (LAN) to support Gigabit to benefit

### Hub

- + Relatively cheap, but...
- - ...not significantly cheaper than switches
- - Very poor performance, especially as network load increases (due to collisions)
- -\+ May or may not require a power supply

Comment: If you're going to call out power supply on 100MBit switch as a minus, shouldn't that be a minus for the Gig switch and hub as well?  Also, most Gig switches will support 10/100, so your other minus really doesn't count.  Lastly, "higher bandwidth" is true between machined on the LAN, but might be misleading as it doesn't increase the bandwidth down through your uplink if the uplink doesn't support Gigabit.

Comment: @Shannon First, I do mention the power issue for hubs; I ignored it for Gigabit because it was mentioned for 100MBit and was implied, and I only wanted to summarise the main distinguishing features for each. Second, it's not clear what you mean by "other minus". Third, of course: this is exactly why I specified that the rest of the LAN must also support Gigabit for any benefit; any source/destination (such as the internet) with <Gigabit in the way will obviously be slower.

Comment: Do you actually need a splitter on both ends? Doesn't the router detect that two (separate) devices are used, on wires 1-4 and 5-8?

Comment: Yes, a splitter must be used at both ends. Using the wires in that way isn't part of the Ethernet standard.

Comment: @M.Mimpen see https://superuser.com/q/764576

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a switch for sure
Less / no collisions
And if you ever have network congestion / problems you can more easily weed out the problem with a sniffer