# Connecting two PCs to single Port(RJ45) of desktop switch

Tags: lan, splitter, rj-45

I have eight PCs on my Network with 8-Port Desktop Switch.Now I want to add one more PC to my Network, but I don't want to use an additional switch.

I have heard it is possible to connect two PCs on single port of RJ45 plug,if it is done through some proper color coding (including RJ45 splitter),but I can't find that proper color coding.

I have done some googling as well,but could fine answer for my question.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

If you really don't want a switch with more ports perhaps you could add a second network card to one of the PCs and bridge the network connection across both so a PC could be plugged into the second network card?

You could also get a small 4 port switch and add that to your 8 port switch giving 7+4 ports.

Comment: I have already considered this bridging option but there is a drawback in it.

The PC with two Network cards must be always on for connectivity.

and I can't manage to get a small 4-port switch.

Comment: to clarify, only possible if two free ports on the destination switch, according to http://superuser.com/questions/104050/ethernet-splitter-switch-question/104847#104847

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  It is strongly not recommended.

It is possible, because these cables are simple copper wire.  If you know how to splice wiring, and know how to put your own ends on the cables (many computer experts have been shown how to do this), you could make a Y-shaped cable that does this.  As long as only one computer is turned on at a time, the switch would not likely notice the difference between that setup, or a setup involving multiple computers.

However, having three or more devices on a single connection is not within specification of how Ethernet is expected to operate.  Computers (or other Ethernet-capable devices) are expected to receive electrical signals and to respond, and full-duplex Ethernet is made with the idea that there is only one response.  Maybe half-duplex Ethernet would work, but you'd likely get a bunch of Ethernet "collisions", which are the main reason why people ditched hubs in favor of more complex devices, called (dumb) switches, long ago.

If your goal is to get two computers to share the connection at the same time, that goal will not work.  A much better way would be to daisy-chain multiple switches.  (Note: I'm not necessarily suggesting that, either.  There can be limits related to this.  A more professional/expensive solution may be to get a different switch with more ports.)

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard it is possible to connect two PCs on single port of RJ45 plug,if it is done through some proper color coding (including RJ45 splitter),but I can't find that proper color coding.

Yes, that's possible. But you'd need two switch ports to connect the two sides of a splitter to, so that wouldn't help you.

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: Sure. To make the RJ45 plug that you can connect two PCs to, you need two connections to the switch, one for each PC. Since the OP doesn't have that, he can't make the single port he could connect the two PCs to.