# Split off cat5 cable to second outlet

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a cat5 drop in my guest room that goes down to the standard outlet level that is wired into a keystone jack.

I decided to mount a tv on the wall halfway up and also want to put a cat5 cable there to hook up to the tv/dvd player.

My question is, can I terminate a short cat5 cable into the keystone jack and run it a few feet up the wall to the tv. Essentially, it's splitting off from the jack and creating another jack.

Is this possible? Any performance loss of both outlets ever happened to be used?

In the image below, I have the keystone hooked up to the drop and another 5 foot cable from that box up the the tv. Before I tap into it though, just wanted to save some time and see if it's even possible or cause issues.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why not a switch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Ethernet splitter and switch](http://superuser.com/questions/104050/difference-between-ethernet-splitter-and-switch)

Comment: I just didn't want to have a switch for 1 outlet. Seems like overkill but I guess if it's the only way. What's the minimum they make, 4 port?

Comment: 5 port switches are the cheapest, you can find 2 port but they are double the cost or more...http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1/191-7556734-0257460?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers&field-keywords=ethernet+switch

Comment: Or use one of these at each end of the cable....http://www.amazon.com/C2G-Cables-37133-Splitter-Combiner/dp/B000Q5UMEI/ref=pd_sim_147_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=41eUNwSAJHL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=0TNPDG74RW3C1BN00A3R

Comment: @Moab that is assuming that both ports would never be used at the same time, correct?

Comment: correct, you need a switch to use both at once.

Comment: This was asked and answered here: http://superuser.com/a/307707/502557

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet over UTP (unshielded twisted pair) cable cannot be spliced nor passively split, and still conform to CAT(5/5e/6/*) specifications.  The topology described requires a switch after the wall jack to provide multiple host connections.