# can i connect two pcs to a router using ethernet without hub and switch?

Tags: networking, ethernet, adsl-router, splitter

I have a router and wanna connect it to two pcs using ethernet cable.

I've seen similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1018323/will-an-ethernet-splitter-work) and it had a good answer but the following pattern that they were talking about was surely not working:

[image: Pattern]

I'm asking what if I use some thing like this:

[image: Ethernet Economiser]

It looks there is no collision and both pcs can has a 2 paired internet connection but I don't know does router can handle it or not.

I know there are switches and hubs but don't mention them.

Comment: This will NOT work.

Comment: Yes it will work.

Comment: @MrEthernet He must have 2 ports on the router which are joined into one cable and then are splitted back to PCs. But if a router have 2 LAN ports OP do not need in this trick - so he has 1-LAN router. In such case the task is unsolvable.

Comment: True. But if he has only a single drop going through a wall and doesn't want to run a second one, and doesn't mind only getting 100 Mbps, then this trick could potentially be useful. https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/pics/office/ethernet-splitter.jpg

Comment: *does router can handle it or not* None standard handles this scheme.

Comment: @akinawhy i must have 2 ports on my router?

Comment: Akina is right. Why can't you use a switch? A 5-port one is probably the same size as your router if that is your concern.

Comment: What is your router model? or at least how many LAN ports it has?

Comment: no right now i even dont have 2 pcs its just a question i dont wanna find a solution for problem  just wanna see this one works or not?

Comment: TP-link-w8151N-wireless and a single ethernet port.

Comment: @raidenthereaper this could work but it would need *two* LAN ports on the router that converged into a single, custom Ethernet cable, which would then diverge at the other end to the two PCs. Only pins 1356 would be used in each RJ45 plug.

Comment: @MrEthernet it's indeed a single LAN port because it's a ADSL router. Rare these days

Comment: @CaldeiraG Very rare! Well I guess he's SOL. Too bad: https://c1.neweggimages.com/ProductImage/33-704-171CVF-05.jpg

Comment: *TP-link-w8151N-wireless and a single ethernet port.* There is 3 variants to connect 2 PCs. Var.1 - use additional switch. Var.2 - connect 2nd PC via 1st one which must have 2 NICs and share the connection. Var.3 - use wireless NIC on one or both PCs. Except to buy another router model, of course...

Comment: @Akina if he wants to stick with Ethernet and avoid WiFi, I think the switch makes the most sense. If he uses PC1 as a proxy server to share the Internet with PC2, PC2 will lose its network connection every time PC1 is turned off. That setup would be more complicated and less reliable. That's actually how I had my first home network set up, also with an ADSL modem in the 90's and it was awful!

Comment: @mrEthernet thanks for answer u mean using splitter in picture finally dosent wroks?u sayd about speed so i know it will be low caus of using 2 paired connection but i wanna know router will understand that there are 2 clients behind port or not.

Comment: @MrEthernet Agreed in general. But I should to buy a router with 4 LAN ports instead - such SOHO device price is low enough.

Comment: @raidenthereaper your router will not understand that there is a custom Ethernet cable connected to it. You must "split" the single Ethernet cable by using a small switch like this first: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712W1xeY2GL._SL1500_.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your router only has one LAN port and would not understand that there is a custom Ethernet cable connected to it:

[image]

You must first "split" the single Ethernet cable coming from your router by using a small switch like this:

[image]

You could then use a custom Ethernet cable like this, with both jacks at one end connected to two different LAN ports at the switch:

[image]