# My school blocks routers and switches is there a way to ssh between 3 devices with one port

Tags: networking, ssh, router

I have 2 raspberry pi's and my computer. I'm living in a dorm that provides 1 Ethernet port. They seem to be blocking my router. Is there a way to have both pi's here and be able to ssh into them. The only thing I can think of is using my router to have a completely local network.

I would still like my computer to have internet access as well. I would prefer to be able to install packages on both pi's.

Comment: You could try [splitters/switches](http://superuser.com/questions/104050/difference-between-ethernet-splitter-and-switch). Not sure how that would affect the ability to ssh. There's always this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/ssh-to-rpi-without-a-network-connection

Comment: @MC10, splitters are about fixing wiring problems; the question is about allowing multiple devices on the same connection.

Comment: *"The only thing I can think of is using my router to have a completely local network"* -- if it's not providing a local network, how is the router configured now?

Answer (score 2):

First off, check with your school's IT department.

1. They might have a solution
2. What you are attempting to do might violate school policy.  You dont want to get suspended, right?

Now on to possible solutions.  I find it hard to believe they are blocking your router.  Is is *possible*, but unlikely.  Plug the router into the dorm's ethernet and power cycle it and leave it there overnight.  Without getting to technical, the switch/router at the other end is checking to see if the MAC has changed, which could be a security concern.  If it doesnt work, then they might be filtering MAC addresses.  Again, this would be a major hassle in a large university, so I doubt this is the case.  If it still doesnt work, most home routers will allow you to change their MAC address.  It sounds like your computer works, so you could put that MAC in your router, and it would work.

If that still doesnt work, you can always add another ethernet adapter to your PC and then bridge that with the port to the wall.  Then you could hook your router to that and your Pis to the router.

Again, ask your school first.  They will offer the best solution, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a wireless dongle to your computer, there are softwares that you can use to create hotspot. If that can help.

Comment: you are assuming his Pis have WiFi... most dont.