# Extending house CAT6 LAN

Tags: lan, home-networking

I have an existing *CAT6* wired network in my two floor house with 6 points (*3* on ground floor and *3* on first floor).

These were added a few years ago when I refurbished the entire house. Each of the points have a cable brought to one point through the walls to the ground floor where I have connected them to a network switch.

However I am due to extend my house to a second floor which I want to add two network points.

The obvious solution to run a cable from each of these two new network points to the ground floor switch. However the issue with this approach is the difficulty in running the cable from the second floor to the ground floor as I would have to open walls to run cables down them.

Is the only solution (other than running cables to the ground floor) to run the two second floor network cables down a stud wall to the first floor, create 2 network point sockets on the wall and then install a second network switch to link the existing network with the new points from the second floor?

Comment: Network splitters don't do what you think they do. You need a switch somewhere.

Comment: There is no such thing as a (standardized) network splitter. Using a double socket and a switch is viable, though still dirty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Ethernet splitter and switch](http://superuser.com/questions/104050/difference-between-ethernet-splitter-and-switch)

Comment: What else would fit your need? Running all the cables to the ground floor; or creating a new "split" seems to be all the opportunities. Thinking out of the box you can use wifi or [power-line network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication), but both consume more energy and less stable / reliable.

Comment: I want to avoid wifi as the router is currently on the ground floor (where the main connection comes in from the street) so the performance would be pretty rubbish. Short of cutting holes in walls to feed it through to the ground floor, the best option currently seems to be bringing the cables to the first floor and setting up a second network switch there.